# Empty line before and after two columns

Tags: columns, line

I use the command sequence:

```
\begin{Parallel}{0.48\textwidth}{0.48\textwidth} %[options]{\linewidth}{\linewidth}
    \selectlanguage{english}
    \ParallelLText{ %
Text for left column.
    }
    \selectlanguage{english}
    \ParallelRText{ %
Text for right column.
    }
    \ParallelPar
\end{Parallel}
```

I want an empty line before and after and the command \newline does not work. How should I proceed?

Comment: Please tell us how or where the `Parallel` environment and the `\ParallelLText`, `\ParallelRText`, and `\ParallelPar` macros are defined.

Comment: Please, use paracol.dtx and paracol.ins.